# Save reference to a python dictionary (from a json file) item in a variable

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm trying to save the reference to a value in a json file where item orders could not be guaranteed. So far, what I have for a dataset like this one:

```
"Values": [
  {
    "Object": "DFC_Asset_05",
    "Properties": [
      {
        "Property": "WeightKilograms",
        "Value Offset": 5
      },
      {
        "Property": "WeightPounds",
        "Value Offset": 10
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Object": "DFC_Asset_05",
    "Properties": [
      {
        "Property": "Name",
        "Value Offset": 25
      },
      {
        "Property": "ShortName",
        "Value Offset": 119
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

and retrieving this object:

```
{
  "Property": "ShortName",
  "Value Offset": 119
}
```

Is a string like this:

```
reference = "[Object=DFC_Asset_06][Properties][Property=Name]"
```

Which looks nice and understandable in a string, but it's very unclean to find the referenced value as I must first parse the reference it with a regex then loop in the data to retrieve the matching item.

Am I doing this wrong? Is there a better way to do this? I looked at the `reduce()` function however it seems like it's made for dictionaries with static data. For example, I could not save the direct keys:

```
reference = "[1][Properties][1]"
reference_using_reduce = [1, "Properties", 1]
```

As they might not always be in that order

Comment: What is the relationship between a dict with `"Property": "ShortName"` and the reference: `"[Object=DFC_Asset_06][Properties][Property=Name]"`? It also looks like you have duplicate items -- do you just want the first one?

Comment: Sorry for the duplicate, I just put dummy information for a quick example and didn't realize I put the same list item twice. The relationship was the filtering (find value where `Object=="DFC_Asset_05"`, then its `Properties`, then the property with `Property=="Name"`. That's how the file is built, not my design. Current answer is perfect though, it can help out to understand better what I needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run "queries" on JSONs without referencing specific indexes using the `pyjq` module:

```
query = (
    '.Values[]'  # On all the items in "Values"
    '|select(."Object" == "DFC_Asset_06")'  # Find key "Object" which holds this value
    '|."Properties"[]'  # And get all the items of "Properties"
    '|select(."Property" == "Name")'  # Where the key "Property" holds the value "Name" 
)
pyjq.first(query, d)
```

Result:

> `{'Property': 'Name', 'Value Offset': 25}`

You can read more about jq in the [documentations](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/).

Comment: WOW! I had no idea such a thing existed! This is the most perfect solution I could hope for, thanks a lot friend!